# Getting multiple pages talking to each other

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am coding a Web app that needs to have multiple tabs/Web pages open. And I would like them to talk to each other. And I don't want the pages to talk to the server. So is it possible with HTML5/JS? By the way they are all on the same domain name.

Comment: I don't think you are thinking in correct terms. a page loads, then unless you make secondary requests are done. I think what you want is something like polling, for one page to be updated as the data is entered in the other.

Comment: " tabs/Web pages" do you mean inside same window or browser tabs?

Comment: If Flash is an option for you, you can use the LocalConnection object and not even need to involve your server for cross-page, and even cross-browser communication on the same client.

Comment: From the same website you would have multiple pages (or tabs) open in the browser... And information could be exchange between each other.

Comment: I know how to make cross-domain work with HTML5... But I have no idea how to make pages in the browser talk to each other. Also I want to avoid flash as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never come across a webapp which used the browsers tab functionality as a means of navigating. I don't want to say it's wrong, because I don't know your particular requirements and, of course, I haven't played with every single webapp in the world.

However, would it not make more sense to implement your own tabbing system within your web app than rely on a feature of the browser which is probably inconsistently implemented and which may be affected by the user's personal settings?

If you're set on this path, and offline functionality is a definite requirement, then I think your only option is using the [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) feature of Flash, as Brad suggests in the comments. I imagine you could create a bridge with [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to pass any data from Flash to the page. The Flash would need do nothing else but marshal the communications (it could occupy a single pixel somewhere on the page). This is a similar approach to the one the [dojotookit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) took with their Flash storage, designed to provide a more capable alternative to cookies.

Answer (score 0):

*I think the answer* here is that what happens in the view, doesn't have to reveal whats happening behind the scenes.

You can make DOM elements on a page communicate with other DOM elements on the page without making a asynchronous call to the server if thats what you're asking.

If you have two tabs in the.. lets say chrome browser, and you want one DOM element to talk to another DOM element on a completely different browser tab. You have to make that asynchronous call to the server which will shoot one back to the other tab. But you don't have to show that happening in the view :) (This can be done with Node.JS/Socket.io, an example would be a chat room built with HTML5/JS)

Hope this helps

Comment: I knew about that... But I am looking for something that will work even if my app is offline. Second, I am not planning to setup Node.js any time soon. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but you may want to look into local storage, or even cookies set via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reliable ways you can have pages in other tabs (or across iframes) talk to each other.

1. The [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API allows pages to send messages even when they are on different domains. There are some security issues to be aware of to avoid malicious behavior. You can read about that in the linked article.
2. [localStorage and sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) will dispatch a ["storage" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage) when they are changed. Using this event you can be notified in other tabs when the data has changed. This only works within the same domain. Because this is all you need, it might be the wiser option to avoid any security issues.